# PowerManager.WakeLock NOT working after the phone going to standby 2+ seconds

Tags: android

I have a Service(SkService) used to wake up my Nexus4(Running Android 4.2.2) from standby via monitoring the ACCELEROMETER,but It does NOT work when the phone goes to standby 2+ seconds.It just works well for me in the 2 following cases:
1.The phone shaked soon after the power key pressed.
2.The phone connected to my laptop

I don't know why. Appreciated if anyone can help me with it!
Here the key code is:

```
    public class SkService extends Service {
private ShakeDetector mShakeDetector;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mShakeDetector = new ShakeDetector(SkService.this);
    mShakeDetector.setOnShakeListener(new onShakeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShake(String value) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Get onShake event with value:" + value);
            Locker.acquireCpuWakeLock(SkService.this);
            Locker.releaseWakeLock();
        }
    });
    mShakeDetector.registerListener();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "SkService on Destroy");
    mShakeDetector.unRegisterListener();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
    }
```

Locker:

```
    public class Locker {

private static PowerManager.WakeLock sCpuWakeLock;

public static void acquireCpuWakeLock(Context context) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Acquiring cpu wake lock");
    if (sCpuWakeLock != null) {
        return;
    }
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);

    KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock kl = km.newKeyguardLock("SKUnlock KeyGuard");
    Log.d(TAG, "Disable keyguard...");
    kl.disableKeyguard();
    Log.d(TAG, "Keyguard disabled and unlock the screen...");

    sCpuWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "SKUnlock");

    sCpuWakeLock.acquire();
    Log.d(TAG, "WakeLock acqiured done");
}

public static void releaseWakeLock() {
    if (sCpuWakeLock == null)
        return;
    sCpuWakeLock.release();
    sCpuWakeLock = null;
    Log.d(TAG, "WakeLock released");
}
    }
```

I got the following log when it works:

```
    04-04 20:23:34.013 D/com.skunlock(31730): Get onShake event with value:Shook 0 times:
    04-04 20:23:34.013 D/com.skunlock(31730): diffTime=64,speed=1588.15. x=2.79, y=-3.25,z=15.27,dX=4.52,dY=4.21,Dirc=Left to Right,accuracy2
    04-04 20:23:34.013 D/com.skunlock(31730): Acquiring cpu wake lock
    04-04 20:23:34.013 D/com.skunlock(31730): Disable keyguard...
    04-04 20:23:34.013 D/com.skunlock(31730): Keyguard disabled and unlock the screen...
    04-04 20:23:34.013 I/PowerManagerService(  525): Waking up from sleep...
    04-04 20:23:34.023 D/com.skunlock(31730): WakeLock acqiured done
    04-04 20:23:34.023 D/com.skunlock(31730): WakeLock released
    04-04 20:23:34.023 I/WindowManager(  525): No lock screen!
    04-04 20:23:34.043 D/SurfaceFlinger(  158): Screen acquired, type=0 flinger=0x41634318
    04-04 20:23:34.043 D/hwcomposer(  158): hwc_blank: Doing Dpy=0, blank=0
    04-04 20:23:34.123 D/hwcomposer(  158): hwc_blank: Done Dpy=0, blank=0
    04-04 20:23:34.143 D/overlay (  158): Set pipe=RGB0 dpy=0; Set pipe=RGB1 dpy=0; Set pipe=VG0 dpy=0; Set pipe=VG1 dpy=0;
```

But I only got the log printed by my app when it does NOT work, there is no any sys log(say,No lock screen):

```
    04-04 20:23:34.333 D/com.skunlock(31730): Get onShake event with value:Shook 0 times:
    04-04 20:23:34.333 D/com.skunlock(31730): diffTime=64,speed=2482.65. x=-1.73, y=-0.91,z=2.05,dX=2.22,dY=7.01,Dirc=Up to Down,accuracy2
    04-04 20:23:34.333 D/com.skunlock(31730): Acquiring cpu wake lock
    04-04 20:23:34.333 D/com.skunlock(31730): Disable keyguard...
    04-04 20:23:34.333 D/com.skunlock(31730): Keyguard disabled and unlock the screen...
    04-04 20:23:34.333 D/com.skunlock(31730): WakeLock acqiured done
    04-04 20:23:34.333 D/com.skunlock(31730): WakeLock released
    04-04 20:23:34.524 D/com.skunlock(31730): Get onShake event with value:Shook 0 times:
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html), it takes care of creating and managing a partial wake lock for you.

You still need to use the permission on the Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```